# Why does drilling underwater hurt me so much?

Tags: glean-2

I've noticed that when I drill in aquatic areas (especially deeper down), I get hurt a lot more.  As I drill at varying depths, it takes a good chunk out of my health.  Why?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This is our first question about this game, so there may or may not be other players here who can answer your question. Good luck.

Comment: You might consider asking this question on some related forums as well. [Here's one](http://glean2.proboards.com/) I found from a link on http://glean-2-guide.wikia.com.

Comment: Thanks, but that forum is blocked on my computer (school laptop), so I figured I'd ask about it on here.  Besides, it might introduce more people to the game.

Answer (score 1):

Being underwater crushes your digger.

You'll note that, on aquatic planets, your temperature gauge is replaced with a pressure gauge, that works a bit differently. The pressure gauge goes up as you swim deeper underwater, like the environmental temperature does, but it *does not* go up as you drill. In other words, there's no "cool down" period for your drill like there is on terrestrial planets.

Instead, the higher the pressure level, the more damage you take when using your drill.  This means you can drill non-stop underwater for as long as your health can take it (and you have oxygen), but you'll lose health steadily the entire time.

The distinction here is hinted at in the in-game help documentation (as in this screenshot of the "Depth" help entry):

[image: Glean 2 Help - Depth]

The same plating upgrades that help you cope with environmental damage on terrestrial planets will also help reduce the pressure damage on water planets.

Comment: Oh, so it could be said that when I drill deeper, it just adds more pressure around me?

Comment: I assume that screenshot is from the game?

Comment: Yeah, that's fine. Your answer just doesn't say where it comes from. If you mention "here's a screenshot from the game's help screen" or wherever it came from, that would give your answer additional credibility. It's also important to cite sources in general. I'm not familiar with the game at all, but if that's from the game, I can still upvote with confidence.